# Logstash conditional logic on custom field from Filebeat

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

I'm new to ELK stack and am starting out by pushing the IIS logs on my Windows Server 2012 application server to Elastic Search using Filebeat and Logstash.

I plan on extending this so that it also pushes up custom application logs which are written by our applications (as opposed to IIS). To do this I'll need to differentiate one type of log from another in Logstash.

So in filebeat.yml I have added a custom field called "log_type":

```
  type: log
  enabled: true
  paths:
     - C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\*\*
  fields:
    log_type: iis
```

In my Logstash I'm trying to perform some conditional logic based on the value of "log_type" but it's not working. If I remove the conditional logic the filter works.

```
filter {
  if [fields.log_type] == "iis" {
    grok {
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:log_timestamp} %{IPORHOST:site} %{WORD:method} %{URIPATH:page} %{NOTSPACE:querystring} %{NUMBER:port} %{NOTSPACE:username} %{IPORHOST:clienthost} %{NOTSPACE:useragent} %{NOTSPACE:referer} %{NUMBER:response} %{NUMBER:subresponse} %{NUMBER:scstatus} %{NUMBER:timetaken:int}"}
    }
    date {
        match => [ "log_timestamp", "ISO8601" ]
        target => "@timestamp"
    }
  }
}
```

I've searched and searched but can't find out how to do this. Would really appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the field in Logstash the syntax should be `[fields][log_type]` rather than `[fields.log_type]`.

Reference

- [Logstash Field References](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/event-dependent-configuration.html#logstash-config-field-references)

Comment: I tried that but it wasn't working. The other examples I came across where that syntax was used was where the child, in this case log_type, is an array. I'll try it again on Monday though and come back here to say whether it worked or not. Thanks for taking the time to reply

Answer (score 1):

Do you have this line in your configuration? `fields_under_root: true`. If yes, you can try simply `[log_type]`, without any prefixes.